# EMGU not installing C++ (Package does not exist)

Tags: c++, opencv, nuget, emgucv

I need EMGU to get my OpenCV project to work (Visual Studio 2019 WinForms), but whenever I try to install it an error comes up saying "Package 'Emgu.CV.4.5.5.4823' does not exist in folder MyProjectName/packages". I've looked around and it doesn't seem to be a very common error. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your project using "package.config" instead of "package reference" to manage nuget packages?

If so, please following this instruction to upgrade "package.config" to "package refenrece":https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/399#issuecomment-767571013

Nuget manager seems to be broken when using "package.config"